# how to add Automatic-Module-Name in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11, java-module, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a non modularised spring boot application and I want to add Automatic-Module-Name. I did the following

```
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Automatic-Module-Name>name-of-my-module</Automatic-Module-Name>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

but I get

**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) on project common-code: Error assembling JAR**

I want to leave all the defaults that spring-boot-maven-plugin would write to MANIFEST.MF and just add Automatic-Module-Name. Any leads are much appreciated.